# React-Three-Fiber / Objects missing in the mobile version

Tags: react-three-fiber

I have made this [test](https://www.zer0day.io/build/) with `<MeshPortalMaterial>` but 2 objets are missing in the mobile version (the diamond and the star) but 2 objets are missing in the mobile version (the diamond and the star) because of this material :

```
<MeshRefractionMaterial
            bounces={1}
            aberrationStrength={0.01}
            envMap={texture}
            toneMapped={false}
          />
```

Are there specific parameters for mobile ?